# How to know which .dsym file would desymbolicate the crash in a group of developers using svn?

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode6

Got the crash report which is containing only the memory addresses (via mail). We work in a group of 4 (onsite and offsite), using smart svn. Now to "de-symbolicate" the crash report, I need the ".dysm". Can anyone enlighten me on these 2 things, an advise I got from my senior peer.

1. Always save the dSYM file from each release so that you can drill on crash reports. Why?
2. Always save a snapshot of each release version in source code control so you can pull out the right code base to match the crash report. Why?

Answer (score 0):

A .dSYM file stands for “debug symbol file.” A crash report gets generated and stored on the device in the event of application crash. It describe the scenario under which the application might have crashed, giving you the proper *backtrace of each thread execution. 
Now symbolication is the issue. Without symbolication one will get the memory address with no clue for proper debugging. So symbolication is like the key to those memory address and the starting point of your debugging operations.

Under normal scenario ; if you are the only developer , you can get the crash logs off a device. For that go to the Xcode’s device window. Drag the .dSYM file and the crash reports.
Under active scenario: If you working in a team, you need to get the dSYM file to symbolicate the crash report and turn them into a meaningful clue.

That requires to save the .dSYM file from every checkout in the SVN. Would need some help from the experts here…So I leave it to you guys.
I came to know dSYM files changes each time our app is compiled due to time stamp or something.
The errors commonly observed are EXC_BAD_ACCESS and EXC_CRASH. 
*(Backtrace is a summary of how your program got where it is.)

Answer (score 0):

I came to know the answer to my question,regarding symbolication.
symbolication only works if the UUID of the binary that caused a crash matches the UUID of the dSYM that is used for symbolication. so for eg.

```
Incident Identifier: DE02F51F-E1F7-4D4C-BE0A-FEE7552242C3
CrashReporter Key:   59a6235172304f0605270d4a8d6edc6d7755118d
Hardware Model:      iPad3,6
Process:             RCSClient [389]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/18DCAE19-3C5D-4811-984F-D53ED87BB185/RCSClient.app/RCSClient
Identifier:          com.RCSClient
Version:             1 (RCS-IOS-PH2-OCT-3901-1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-11-13 18:51:25.612 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-11-13 18:40:23.444 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105
```

getting :**Version:             1 (RCS-IOS-PH2-OCT-3901-1.0)** is the key.